# How to force assumptions for solving a system of equations?

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages, assumptions

I am trying to solve a system of equations for the panel method using complex functions. Mathematica would not even attempt to produce a solution for the `bcs` term even if I assume real values for $\Gamma$. Also, how do I assume that all values of the $\Gamma$ array are positive and real?

```
$Assumptions = Γ[1] ∈ Reals;
n = 1;
Ξu[ζ_] := ζ;
Ξv[θ_, R_, ζ_, ζ0_] := (-I)*Sum[Γ[k]*Log[ζ - ((k - 0.75)/n)*R*Exp[I*θ] - ζ0], {k, 1, n}]; 
dΞ[ζ_] := Evaluate[D[Ξu[ζ] + Ξv[θ, R, ζ, ζ0], ζ]]; 
dΞcl[j_] = dΞ[(j - 0.25)/n R Exp[I θ] - ζ0];
bc[j_] := Evaluate[Re[dΞcl[j]] Sin[θ] - Im[dΞcl[j]] Cos[θ]] == 0;
bcs = With[{θ = 0.1, R = 1, ζ0 = 0}, Evaluate[Array[bc, n]]]

Solve[bcs]
```

[image: results]

Comment: Please share the code in copyable form, so that other users can play with it. No one wants to retype all this code (and double check for correct transition). This will raise your chances for getting quick and competent help.

Comment: Welcome Ali! To make the most of Mma.SE start by **taking the [tour] now**. It will **help us to help you** if you write an [excellent question](https://goo.gl/BqKxV3). [Edit](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX) if improvable, show due diligence, give brief context, include **minimal working example** of code and data in **[formatted form](https://goo.gl/ELLhTX)**. As you receive **give back**, vote and answer questions, keep the site useful, be kind, correct mistakes and share what you have learned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
n = 3;
$Assumptions = (Γ /@ Range[n]) ∈ Reals;

Ξu[ζ_] = ζ;
Ξv[θ_, R_, ζ_, ζ0_] := (-I)*Sum[Γ[k]*
     Log[ζ - ((k - 3/4)/n)*R*Exp[I*θ] - ζ0], {k, 1, n}];
dΞ[ζ_] := Evaluate[D[Ξu[ζ] + Ξv[θ, R, ζ, ζ0], ζ]];
dΞcl[j_] = dΞ[(j - 1/4)/n R Exp[I θ] - ζ0];
bc[j_] := Evaluate[Re[dΞcl[j]] Sin[θ] - Im[dΞcl[j]] Cos[θ]] == 0;
bcs = Array[bc, n] /. {θ -> 1/10, R -> 1, ζ0 -> 0} // FullSimplify;

sol = Solve[bcs, Evaluate[Γ /@ Range[n]]]

(* {{Γ[1] -> -(5/16) Sec[1/5] Sin[1/10], 
     Γ[2] -> -(1/8) Sec[1/5] Sin[1/10], 
     Γ[3] -> -(1/16) Sec[1/5] Sin[1/10]}} *)
```

Verifying solution

```
And @@ (bcs /. sol[[1]])

(* True *)
```

**EDIT:**

```
sol /. (x_ -> y_) :> x -> N[y]

{{Γ[1] -> -0.0318325, Γ[2] -> -0.012733, Γ[3] -> -0.00636649}}
```

Note that there are no positive solutions.

To assume that all `Γ` are positive (and hence real)

```
$Assumptions = Thread[Γ /@ Range[n] > 0]

(* {Γ[1] > 0, Γ[2] > 0, Γ[3] > 0} *)
```

Comment: I think fixing the boundary conditions will give the correct sign for gamma values, but getting the solution to work is good enough for now. Thank you!